# How to migrate data from Solo to Relay Chain?

Tags: relay-chain, solo-chain

I'm trying to migrate data from one existing solo chain to relay chain. How should I achieve it?
I`m taking ideas from Centrifuse chain which is migrating accounts and their balances, proxy,and vesting. But i need to migrate staking ledger,contracts DeletionQueue, and  Contracts ContractInfoOf .

Please guide me through this migration

Comment: This is a tutorial on how to make the transition here: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/connect-a-local-parachain/

Comment: I need to migrate existing solo chain data to relay chain, not the communication part between relay chain and parachain

Comment: What kind of data do you want to migrate?